# Convert XML based domain model description to EMF like domain model

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-emf, emf

I'm not sure that my question is correct from EMF expert point of view. I investigate the problem

1. I have xml file that describe domain model(set of datatypes) and corresponded xsd file that can be used for validation given domain model description
2. This xml file can be changed by third party software. This updated is provided very seldom (one/two times in 3-4 months). In this case saving domain model as set of java class and rebuild it more suitable from other parts of application point of view

My goal is convert xml domain model to EMF domain model description, then generate genmodel file and then generate domain model as set of Java classes.  how to convert xml domain model to EMF domain model description automatically? I found easy way to create ecore file from xsd. Are the any way to load my xml file using ecore description and save it as EMF like model for genearting Java class as next step

Thank you in advance
Alexander

Answer (score 1):

As you yourself found out, you need to crate emf model out of schema.
Steps which I could immediately think of

1. Create ecore out of schema.
2. Generate genmodel.
3. Generate model, edit and editor.
4. Open manifest editor of generated editor plugin and check what is the file extension of your model instance file.   *This is the file extension which your xml file will stand with*
5. Right click on generated project and launch as eclipse application.
6. Create a project and place your xml file with same extension as in step 4.
7. Double click on the file.

Now your xml file is loaded into emf model and displayed in editor. Now its your task to build your own UI based on your customer needs using the emf model.

Please note that you can always update the schema file, generate ecore file, update the existing model. Let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: Thank you for answer,I've tried to do these steps. My first question is I did not found in manifaest.mf any information about extension of model. Thr next question is when I load my xml file to generated editor I obtain the following error message org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'null' not found. (platform:/resource/model-editor/model/types.xml, 1, 13). I suppose my xml file is not well done. By the way this file is generated by third party software

Comment: Also I have org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.ClassNotFoundException: Class 'type-model' is not found or is abstract. (platform:/resource/model-editor/model/types.xmi, 1, 13). I checked all required package are exported and all required plugins are included in dependencies

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EMF-FAQ#How_do_I_use_EMF_in_standalone_applications_.28such_as_an_ordinary_main.29.3F.    Check the link . You will get solution. If it doesnt help, jus comment here, I will try to find the solution after my office hrs

Comment: Did you give a try. Try giving below options hsshmap as input to load and save method call.. have a look at "http://java.dzone.com/articles/emf-reading-model-xml-–-how".    Copy paste the link. It s not working directly:-(